# apex - Internal server error when getting Element of a List of Maps

Tags: apex, error, list, map

I am passing a List of Maps to my controller from the client-side javascript, and when trying to access an element of this list, an internal error is thrown.

Here is an example of the problem :

Javascript :

```
saveData : function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.saveDipping");

    var indexList = [];
    indexList.push(new Map());
    indexList.push(new Map());
    indexList[0].sp = 1;
    indexList[0].sp2 = 1;
    console.log(indexList[0]);

    action.setParams({
        "indexListMap" : indexList
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert("ok !");
        } else {
            var errors = response.getError();
            alert("code : " + errors[0].message);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Apex controller :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void saveDipping (List<Map<String, String>> indexListMap) {

        System.debug(indexListMap);
        System.debug(indexListMap[0]);
}
```

Note that the first debug works fine, and we can check the form of the list, but the second one throws the internal error.

Is there a different way to pass the list of maps as argument to make this work ?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to coerce a String into a Decimal. Have you tried adding quotes?

Comment: Yes, sorry, actually this was part of a previous code where I was trying to manipulate Integer instead of String. But this wasn't the origin of the problem.
But thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this bug on a Visualforce page a few years ago and logged a support ticket, I guess they haven't fixed it.  `String.valueOf` still works on the `List`, so you may also be able to use the `JSON` library.  You could try doing:

```
indexListMap = (List<Map<String, String>>)JSON.deserialize(
                JSON.serialize(indexListMap), List<Map<String, String>>.class);
```

Additionally, you could serialize the `List` to JSON in your Lightning component and pass that to the controller, then deserialize it in the controller.

Comment: That worked perfectly, it solved my problem, thank you very much !
It also works on different kind of maps, such as List<Map<String, Integer>>.

Thanks again !